# Limit study with varying $\lambda$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have to determine the limit of this function based on the varying parameter lambda.

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\sin^3x-x\arctan(x^2)+\lambda x^5}{x^7}$$

my first approach was to use Taylor to approximate the functions in the numerator but that still led me to an undetermined $\frac00$. My second approach was using De L'Hopital's theorem. Using that, and deriving twice the function we get to:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{f''(x)}{g''(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{6\sin{x}\cos^2{x}-3\sin^3{x}-\frac1{1+x^4}-\frac{4x(1+x^4)-8x^6}{{1+x^4}^2}+20\lambda x^3}{42x^5}$$

This simply diverges to $-\infty$ for whatever $\lambda$. However, I'm a bit skeptic about the result since this is an exam exercise and I'm pretty sure that if the professor added this lambda, it's because the limit converges in two different spots with different lambdas.

So I'm mainly asking the approach I followed here is correct or if there are any conditions that prevented me from using De L'Hopital maybe and should have used another approach

EDIT: There was a typo in the assignment which was $\sin^3x-x\arctan(x^2)$ I fixed it in the top limit too

Comment: Taylor expansion (up to $x^7 + o(x^7)$) should work, can you please show how it went? Also, your derivative of $x \arctan x^2$ doesn't seem right: the function is odd, so its second derivative should also be zero at $0$.

Comment: I don't know about the uses of real analysis theorems abroad, but in France, de L'Hospital rule is very uncommon, and is useful in very precise cases. It seems to be the converse for American students. I would do the same as @mihaild suggested, this will work no matter what. Also you know that some $\lambda$ should work since you only have odd functions which means you should not have even terms in your Taylor expansions (so no $x^6$)...

Comment: At penultimate term, it is $-8x^5$

Comment: @JulesBesson. At the time I was a student, we used it quite a lot. Things change with time ! Cheers :)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes I was told this was infamous back in the days :)

Comment: @JulesBesson formally we need to verify that coefficients at $x$ and $x^3$ are zero, then we are guaranteed that exactly one $\lambda$ will work.

Comment: L_Cleo, $\,\sin^3\!x+x\arctan(x^2)=2x^3-\frac12x^5-\frac9{40}x^7+o(x^7)$. Consequently, for any $\lambda\in\Bbb R$, it does not exist your limit.

Comment: Since $\sin^3 x + x \arctan(x^2) +\lambda x^5 = 2x^3+O(x^5)$ the limit doesn't exists independently of the value of $\lambda$. My guess is that there's a typo, it should be $\sin^3 x \color{red}{-} x \arctan(x^2) +\lambda x^5$, so there will be a unique value of $\lambda$ for which the limit exists.

Comment: @mihaild yes this was only insight

Comment: L_Cleo, if jjagmath is right, then $$\sin^3\!x-x\arctan(x^2)=-\frac12x^5+\frac{53}{120}x^7+o(x^7)\,.$$ Consequently you limit exists for $\lambda=\frac12$ and its value is $\frac{53}{120}\,.$

Comment: @mihaild and Angelo thanks for the explanation on Taylor's expansion it helped me a lot get on the right path (however Angelo I think there is something wrong on your expansion, or mine I'm trying to figure it out).

Comment: And @jjagmath thanks a lot for letting me realize there is in fact a typo, and after messaging my uni professor he corrected the assignment fixing the typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @jjagmath I messaged my professor and made him realize there was a typo in the assignment, it was actually $-x\arctan{x^2}$ and not $+$.

I re-did the limit using Taylor expansion (thanks to @mihaild and @Angelo that helped me realize where I did wrong the Taylor expansion typo left alone) and realized I did used improperly the fact that the $\sin{x}$ is actually cubed.

I'm deciding to spend some time and answer my own question since it might still be useful for anyone struggling to use Taylor expansions and understanding up to what $o(x)$ one should go. Anyways let's walkthrough the solution.

Let's expand $\sin{x}$
$$\sin{x}=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+o(x^5)$$

In fact

$$\sin^3\!{x}=\big(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+o(x^5)\big)^3 =\\= x^3-\frac{x^5}{2}+\frac{13}{120}x^7+o(x^7)$$

Meanwhile expanding $\arctan{x}$:

$$\arctan{(x^2)}=x^2-\frac{x^6}{3}+o(x^6)$$

so the whole thing can be re-written as:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{x^3-\frac{x^5}{2}+\frac{13}{120}x^7-x^3+\frac{x^7}3+\lambda x^5+o(x^7)}{x^7}$$

so

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{(\lambda - \frac12)x^5 + \frac{53}{120}x^7+o(x^7)}{x^7}$$

So this brings us to the following:

- for $\lambda<\frac12$ then $f(x)\rightarrow-\infty$
- for $\lambda>\frac12$ then $f(x)\rightarrow+\infty$
- for $\lambda=\frac12$ then $f(x)\rightarrow\frac{53}{120}$

Comment: L_Cleo, your answer contains mistakes. Actually $$\sin^3\!x=x^3-\frac12x^5+\frac{13}{120}x^7+o(x^7)\;.$$

Comment: Can you point me towards them, I went through it again trying to understand how would $\frac{53}{120}$ would come up

Comment: I re-did the math @Angelo but $\sin^3{x}=\big(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+o(x^5)\big)^3 = x^3-\frac{x^5}{2}+\frac{x^7}{12}+o(x^7)$. Can you re-check the math on your side just to be sure?

Comment: L_Cleo, look at here : $$\sin^3\!x=\left(x-\frac{x^3}6+\frac{x^5}{120}+o(x^5)\right)^3=\\=x^3+3x^2\left(-\frac{x^3}6\right)+3x\left(-\frac{x^3}6\right)^{\!2}+3x^2\frac{x^5}{120}+o(x^7)=\\=x^3-\frac12x^5+\frac1{12}x^7+\frac1{40}x^7+o(x^7)=\\=x^3-\frac12x^5+\frac{13}{120}x^7+o(x^7)\;.$$

Comment: But isn't it enough to stop at the second order of the Taylor expansion?

Comment: L_Cleo. No, it is not enough otherwise you do not get the correct term $x^7$, indeed you forgot to write $\frac1{40}x^7$ and for that reason your result is not correct.

Comment: @L_Cleo your Taylor expansion is not correct, $\sin(x) = x - x^3 / 3! + x^5 / 5! + o(x^5) \neq x - x^3 /3! + o(x^5)$.

Comment: Thanks guys, fixed it. The math should be right now

Comment: @L_Cleo, still there are mistakes. If you allow me, I will correct them.

Comment: Go on please, I'd really appreciate that

Answer (score 2):

Taylor expansion is of course the best method to use here, following your first idea to proceed by l'Hopital we obtain

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\sin^3x-x\arctan(x^2)+\lambda x^5}{x^7}$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{3\sin^2x\cos x-\arctan(x^2)-\frac{2x^2}{x^4+1}+5\lambda x^4}{7x^6}$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{6\sin x\cos^2 x-3\sin^3 x-\frac{6x}{x^4+1}+\frac{8x^5}{(x^4+1)^2}+20\lambda x^3}{42x^5}$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{6\cos^3 x-21\sin^2 x\cos x-\frac{6}{x^4+1}+\frac{64x^4}{(x^4+1)^2}-\frac{64x^8}{(x^4+1)^3}+60\lambda x^2}{210x^4}$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{21\sin^3 x-60\sin x\cos^2 x+\frac{280x^3}{(x^4+1)^2}-\frac{1024x^7}{(x^4+1)^3}+\frac{768x^{11}}{(x^4+1)^4}+120\lambda x}{840x^3}$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{183\sin^2 x\cos x-60\cos^3 x+\frac{840x^2}{(x^4+1)^2}-\frac{9408x^6}{(x^4+1)^3}+\frac{20736x^{10}}{(x^4+1)^4}+\frac{12288x^{14}}{(x^4+1)^5}+120\lambda }{2520x^2}$$

and from here we see that a necessary condition for the existence of a finite limit is

$$120\lambda-60\cos^3 x \to 120\lambda-60=0 \implies \boxed{\lambda=\frac12}$$

with

$$\frac{60-60\cos^3 x}{x^2}=60\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}(1+\cos x+\cos^2 x) \to 60\cdot \frac12\cdot 3=90$$

and then from the latter expression with $\lambda=1/2$ we obtain

$$\small \frac1{2520}\left(183\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}\cos x+\frac{60-60\cos^3 x}{x^2}+\frac{840}{(x^4+1)^2}-\frac{9408x^4}{(x^4+1)^3}+\frac{20736x^{8}}{(x^4+1)^4}+\frac{12288x^{12}}{(x^4+1)^5} \right)\to $$

$$\to \frac1{2520}\left(183+90+840-0+0+0 \right)=\frac{1113}{2520}=\boxed{\frac{53}{120}}$$